# What does boutade mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I am reading an essay on Pinocchio that contains the following sentence.  I can not find a meaning for ***boutade.***

"That Pinocchio is the literary text that more than any other has been read by Italians in the twentieth century must make one wary about dismissing Prezollini's judgement as a mere ***boutade.***

Comment: I think this is not Italian, but English or French.

Comment: Thus probably this question shouldn't be asked at this site, but at english.stackexchange.com or at french.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Well, since it was in a book about Pinocchio, and a translation thereof, it never occurred to me that it was not Italian!  That was stupid of me, I guess, but would explain why I could not find a dictionary entry for it.  I wonder, however, if there are commonly used foreign words used in Italian?  I know that in English, we have a lot of them!

Comment: @Msfolly There are hundreds of them, mainly from [English](http://nuovoeutile.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/300_parole-2.jpg), [French](http://www.carlalattanzi.it/viewdoc.asp?co_id=91&tree=122) and [German](http://tokiohotel483italia.forumfree.it/m/?t=29797484).

Comment: By the way, you can also find the word *boutade* in [most](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/B/boutade.php) [good](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/B/boutade.shtml) [Italian](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/boutade/) [dictionaries](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/boutade).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Well, it wasn't in the last dictionary I was told to reference by this very site.  AND, if it is in a few Italian dictionaries, why on earth was it closed?    Honestly, using this site is very difficult.

Comment: Indeed, the fact that *boutade* is or isn't in Italian dictionaries isn't really relevant, since it is a French word used in an English text, and that is why the question is off-topic here.

Comment: @Msfolly Its French and as such its off-topic here, some dictionaries include it and they do the same for other foreign languages used in Italy that’s all, but even the Merriam-Webster includes it. Don’t be scared by the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Boutade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boutade)* is the same as *caprice* or *whim*. The meaning of the quoted sentence, therefore, is that *[Prezzolini's idea](https://www.unz.org/Pub/SaturdayRev-1940feb17-00014)* - that *Pinocchio* isn't just a children's book, but it's the key for a deeper understanding of Italy - should be taken seriously and shouldn't be considered a *mot d'esprit*, a mere witticism.